# Hardware programming with Masm64

Tags: assembly, 64-bit, masm

I recently got back into Assembly Language programming with masm x64 under Windows 10, using Visual Studio.
I wrote a simple application which makes Windows API calls to read the machine local date and time, convert it to the local regional settings format (found in Control Panel). And finally output this via a dialog box.

I learnt alot (and remembered some stuff), e.g. 64-bit architecture, registers, calling convention, shadow/spill space, 16-byte aligning the stack, Unicode strings, concatenating (string) variables...

**Background** The last time I used assembly was back in Uni some 25 years ago.
And that was under MS DOS using masm and tasm. Which is why I'm partial to masm, because of my roots.

Now being a purist, I would like to still program under Windows 10 but access some of the hardware directly without using Windows API calls.
Understandly, programming under Windows in user mode means you have no choice but to use the Windows API.
But programming in assembly and making out-of-process calls (i.e. Win API calls) just sounds so inefficient!

So (I guess) the only other option under Windows to access hardware is to program in kernal mode (ring 0).
I belive this is possible with the Windows 10 WDK. Unfortunatly looking into the WDK it seems to be all about C++. And assembly isn't even mentioned.

I wouldn't dream of graphics programming by accessing the graphics card in assembly these days, as DirectX and OpenGL have done this for you. Just simply use them.

**Question**
Given there is not much masm 64 information out there for Windows programming, but thankfully the Intel 64 bit architecture manuals are great!

Can anyone please provide information or point me in the right direction?

I'm not trying to program anything specific. I just love learning and programming in assembly and get alot of enjoyment out of it.

Comment: as far as access goes assembly doesnt really buy you anything you cant access in C.  So whatever kernel functions are available for accessing things you can certainly access in asm, just make the same system calls.  it is definitely not the dos days, it is pretty much windows of any version days, where if you want direct access you have to punch through the protection (reprogram the protection maps in a driver), or write a driver.  again, any call you can make in C or C++ you can make in asm, just disassemble some C++ if unsure how to craft the call...

Comment: @dwelch Thanks... I'll give that a go. So far I have been doing this with WinAPI calls, i.e. lookup up WinAPI function spec in MSDN in C++ (lpcstr, lpwstr...), then work out how to call it in asm. Cheers.

Comment: @Thomas Veil - I would recommend starting from this set of tutorials posted in youtube by What's a Creel which take you through complete 64 bit instruction set and helps interlink with the main() provided by C/C++. It also covers how to call the primitives at various levels from an assembly language routine. And no, this is not intrinsic inline assembly :-) Have fun

Comment: @quasar66 These C++ tutorials will help when using the Kernel-Mode Driver Framework (KMDF) which is also written in C++, then you simply add your ASM source files or reference your ASM binaries to the KMDF project. Thanks!!!